# How to include limited app in UIActivityViewController default share

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller

I wanted to include only 3 apps teams , messages and outlook in UIActivityViewController but I am unable to find any way so I tried to use excludedActivityTypes for all popular apps I found but then also some of the apps like telegram , microsoft todo are showing in the share list.

Can anyone please help me here.

I tried below code

```
 activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = \[
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.dubox.drive.ShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.xiaomi.mihome.shareextension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.markupAsPDF,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.mail,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.print,
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.reminders.sharingextension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType.copyToPasteboard,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToWeibo,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFlickr,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTwitter,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFacebook,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTencentWeibo,
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.one97.paytm.JarvisShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.facebook.Facebook.ShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "pinterest.ShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.facebook.Messenger.ShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.tinyspeck.chatlyio.share"), // Slack!
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "ph.telegra.Telegraph.Share"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.google.Drive.ShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.toyopagroup.picaboo.share"), // Snapchat!
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "wefwef.YammerShare"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.fogcreek.trello.trelloshare"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.hammerandchisel.discord.Share"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.google.Gmail.ShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.google.inbox.ShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.riffsy.RiffsyKeyboard.RiffsyShareExtension"), //GIF Keyboard by Tenor
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.google.hangouts.ShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.ifttt.ifttt.share"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.facebook"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.google.Maps.ShareTextShareExtension"),
        UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "us.zoom.videomeetings.Extension")
     \]
```